# Pinescript: Setting SL & TP using rma at entry position

Tags: pine-script

Good day everyone.
I'm looking to set TP & SL of a position based on ATR (rma) during entry position. So I've used bar index during open trade but I've encountered "series int" error for rma. Here's my code that fails, would appreciate anyone who can shed some light! TQ.

```
barsSinceLastEntry = strategy.opentrades > 0 ? bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1) : na

atr_ts = ta.rma(ta.tr(true), barsSinceLastEntry) * 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `var` to store the atr value at entry. Since it is a `var`, its value won't change unless you specifically do so.

```
var float atr_at_entry = na

is_new_position = ((strategy.position_size[1] == 0) and (strategy.position_size != 0)) or ((strategy.position_size[1] * strategy.position_size) == -1)    
atr_val = ta.rma(ta.tr(true), 14)    
atr_at_entry := is_new_position ? atr_val[1] : atr_at_entry  // If it is a new position, write the new ATR value, keep the old one otherwise

// Use atr_at_entry for your TP/SL calculations
```